# Angular Validators.required not working in formArray when control value is initialized

Tags: angular

im working in Angular 14 project and i use reactiveForms.
this is my code:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      userName: [''],
      email: [''],
      rateList: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.group({
          issueDate: ['', Validators.required],
          comment: ['', Validators.required]
        })
      ])
    });
}

    
addNewFormGroup(): UntypedFormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
          issueDate: [myObject.issueDate, Validators.required],// the validation is not working for this field  with init value
          comment: [myObject.comment, Validators.required] // the validation is not working for this field  with init value
    });
}

// method called by the IHM to add an element   
 addNewElement() {
    (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('rateList')).push(this.addNewFormGroup());
}

getFormArrayControls(controlName) {
    return (<FormArray>this.myForm.get(controlName)).controls;
}
```

the problem is : when i empty the two fields issueDate & comment in the IHM the :

```
{{getFormArrayControls('rateList')[i].get('issueDate').hasError('required')}} and `{{getFormArrayControls('rateList')[i].get('comment').hasError('required')}}` returns false for both fields
```

when i remove `myObject.issueDate & myObject.issueDate in addNewFormGroup` method . the fields become required and the validation works.
do you have any idea what's the wrong with my code

this is my code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vf3ztk?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: It's looks like work, see a [little stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zxbtqs?file=src%2Fmain.ts). Well I imagine is "this.myObject". NOTE: You can use also:`myForm.hasError('required','rateList.'+i+'.comment')`. BTW the code become cleaner if you use a getter to the formArray

Comment: @Eliseo thanks for your answer i forked the project this is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vf3ztk?file=src%2Fmain.ts could you please check it. but i have a compilation error even i don't have it in my IDE

Comment: I added an answer. Your problem is related to type reactive Forms

Answer (score 0):

```
      issueDate: [myObject.issueDate, Validators.required],
      comment: [myObject.comment, Validators.required]
```

myObject is here undefined... Either you create the object or use this.myObject

Comment: thanks for your answer. in fact even if i change myObject.issueDate with hardcoded value '01/05/2023' (just to test)  the required is not working

Answer (score 0):

About my comment.

Personal opinion: the Typed Reactive Forms is a really headache, we can learn about it in [this](https://netbasal.com/typed-reactive-forms-in-angular-no-longer-a-type-dream-bf6982b0af28) or in [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms).

I create a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u5rq1n?file=src%2Fmain.ts) based in the before but stricted type. Basically I use `fombuilder.nonNullable`and use "map" to create the formArray.

Really to mannage a FormArray of FormGroup I usually create a function that return a formGroup. This allow us to have the creation of the formGroup in one unique function and not repeat code.

```
  getRateGroup(element:any=null)
  {
    element=element ||  { issueDate: '', comment: '' };
    return this.formBuilder.nonNullable.group({
      issueDate: [element.issueDate, Validators.required], 
      comment: [element.comment, Validators.required] 
    })
  }
```

This allow us, e.g. use

```
(<FormArray>this.myForm.get('rateList')).push(this.getRateGroup())
```

Or simplify the functions in the way

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.myForm = this.formBuilder.nonNullable.group({
      userName: [''],
      email: [''],
      rateList: this.formBuilder.nonNullable.array([
          this.getRateGroup()
      ]),
    });
}

loadData(dataList: any): FormArray{
    return new FormArray(
         dataList.map((element: any) => this.getRateGroup(element)
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks for your code the POC is working but in my code it's not wkoring maybe because  im calling     this.myForm.setControl('rateList', this.loadData(this.mylist));
inside subscribe of an ngrx selector . the hasError('required') return true only for the new added element but it's not working for the elements loaded by loadData() method